# r - how to have several columns from a data frame on the x axis?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, where there is a column for days (1 to 30/31) and one for months (1 to 12). I want to plot another column over time, but can only figure out how to do it over one of the two time columns. Is there a way to plot it over both columns such that for the first month all the days appear on the x-axis and then for the next etc.

Comment: Create a date column that combines your day and month columns. See `?strftime`, or perhaps more simply, `?as.Date` (note the capital D).

Comment: something like `your_data$date = as.Date(paste("2015", your_data$month, your_data$day, sep = "-"))` should work. If you want more help, you'll probably need to make you question reproducible by sharing data. Something like `dput(head(your_data, 10))` is best.